# get hibernating mapping from application code

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way to get the hibernate mapping from within my application code?
 for example, for the below mapping, I want to return  createdDate given created_date from my application.

```
 <property
        name="createdDate"
        type="java.lang.String"
        column="created_date"
        length="45"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably could do so by using `Configuration` to get the `Property` you need, for example:-

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
Property property = configuration.getClassMapping("EntityName").getProperty("createdDate");

... // use the API from Property
```

Here's [the javadoc for Property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/mapping/Property.html) where you can get the information you need.